# Наполнить const char* данными из unsigned char

Tags: c++, c, char, преобразование, const

Я формирую буфер из значений типа `unsigned char`. Значения хранятся в HEX, то есть `0x00`, `0x2e` и так далее. Функция, работающая с этими данными принимает на вход `const char*`. Как корректно преобразовать мой буфер к типу `const char*` в C/C++?

Comment: Проще всего - используя `union`.

Comment: union - это немного перебор. Тут обычное приведение типов подойдет или memcpy.

Comment: т.е. ты должен преобразовать байты (числа в hex) в строку я правильно понял ?
uint8_t[] в char[] ?
Можно приведение типов static_cast<> или можно std::copy() использовать,
или если нужно реально в строку (0x14 - > "0x14") то lexical_cast<>, itoa наконец...
Это что-то типо вывода дампа ?

Comment: Пример хоть покажите.

Comment: Спасибо, @KoVadim! Действительно, `memcpy` решил эту задачу